# Add json data recursively to json object python

Tags: python, json, recursion

I have this initial json which I made in this piece of code:

```
menu_structure = []
menu_root = cursor.fetchall()
for menu_item in menu_root:
    menu_structure.append({"name": menu_item[1]})
    get_tree_branch(lang=lang, id_parent=menu_item[0], parent_name=menu_item[1], menu_structure=menu_structure,
                        cursor=cursor)
```

JSON 1

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fish",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Fish of two waters"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sea water fish"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fresh water fish"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Seafood"
  }
]
```

I made a sql petition to see if *Fish of two waters* has a children, if it has a children then I only receive a string with the name of children and I want to add the children to the json object like this:

JSON 2

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fish",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Fish of two waters",
        "children": [
        {
           "name": "Test fish"
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sea water fish"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fresh water fish"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Seafood"
  }
]
```

To do that in my python code I do this:

```
def get_tree_branch(lang: str, id_parent: int, menu_structure, cursor):
    sql_query = "select ps_category.id_category, name from ps_category Right Join ps_category_lang On " \
                "ps_category.id_category = ps_category_lang.id_category Right Join ps_lang on " \
                "ps_category_lang.id_lang = ps_lang.id_lang where ps_category.is_root_category = 0 " \
                "AND ps_category.id_parent like %s AND ps_lang.lang_name = %s"

    sql_params = (id_parent, lang)
    cursor.execute(query=sql_query, args=sql_params)
    menu_branch = cursor.fetchall()

    if menu_branch:
        menu_structure[len(menu_structure) - 1]["children"] = []

        for menu_item in menu_branch:
            menu_structure[len(menu_structure) - 1]["children"].append({"name": menu_item[1]})
            get_tree_branch(lang=lang, id_parent=menu_item[0], menu_structure=menu_structure, cursor=cursor)

    else:
        return
```

But that code instead does this json:

JSON 3

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fish",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Test fish"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sea water fish"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fresh water fish"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Seafood"
  }
]
```

Any suggestions on how to create a json object like the JSON 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I did this, hope it helps

```
def get_tree_menu(lang: int):
    test_db = init_database()
    cursor = test_db.cursor()
    menu_structure = []

    sql_query = """select c.id_category, cl.name from ps_category_lang as cl
                    left join ps_category c on cl.id_category = c.id_category
                    where c.is_root_category = 1 AND cl.id_lang = %s AND c.active = 1 
                    order by c.position asc"""
    cursor.execute(query=sql_query, args=lang)
    menu_root = cursor.fetchall()

    id_category = 0
    name = 1
    for menu_item in menu_root:
        menu_structure.append({"name": menu_item[name]})
        get_tree_branch(lang=lang, id_parent=menu_item[id_category], parent_name=menu_item[name],
                        menu_structure=menu_structure, cursor=cursor)

    cursor.close()
    close_database(test_db=test_db)
    return menu_structure


def get_tree_branch(lang: int, id_parent: int, parent_name: str, menu_structure, cursor):
    sql_query = """select c.id_category, cl.name from ps_category_lang as cl
                    left join ps_category c on cl.id_category = c.id_category
                    where c.is_root_category = 0 AND c.id_parent = %s AND cl.id_lang = %s AND c.active = 1 
                    order by c.position asc"""

    sql_params = (id_parent, lang)
    cursor.execute(query=sql_query, args=sql_params)
    menu_branch = cursor.fetchall()

    id_category = 0
    name = 1
    if menu_branch:
        for menu_item in menu_branch:
            menu_structure = create_json_structure(json_object=menu_structure, search_value=parent_name,
                                                   child_name=menu_item[name])
            get_tree_branch(lang=lang, id_parent=menu_item[id_category], parent_name=menu_item[name],
                            menu_structure=menu_structure, cursor=cursor)
    else:
        return


def create_json_structure(json_object: any, search_value: str, child_name: str):
    """Recursively search for values of key in JSON tree and add a child to the JSON element."""
    if isinstance(json_object, dict):
        for key, value in json_object.items():
            if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                create_json_structure(json_object=value, search_value=search_value, child_name=child_name)
            else:
                if value == search_value:
                    try:
                        json_object["children"].append({
                            "parentName": search_value,
                            "name": child_name
                        })
                    except KeyError:
                        json_object["children"] = []
                        json_object["children"].append({
                            "parentName": search_value,
                            "name": child_name
                        })
                    break

    elif isinstance(json_object, list):
        for item in json_object:
            create_json_structure(json_object=item, search_value=search_value, child_name=child_name)
    return json_object
```